# MS Test cases for MVC controller class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have the below action methods defined Controller class.

```
 public ActionResult Register()
        {
            RegisterViewModel model = new RegisterViewModel();
            model.UserType = 2;
            return View(model);
        }
```

I need to write the test cases for these methods.

```
AccountController controller = new AccountController();
        // Act
        ViewResult result = controller.Register() as ViewResult;
        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual("Register", result.ViewName);
        RegisterViewModel model = new RegisterViewModel();
         model.UserType = 2;
         Assert.AreEqual(model.UserType, ((RegisterViewModel)result.ViewData.Model).UserType);
```

The above code throws error saying

> Additional information: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:.
>   Actual:<>.

I understood the expected type has not returned. But Dont know what is the correct way to write a test case for the controller action methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Account controller - Register method - when you write the return statement -- something like this-

```
return View(model);
```

Try to mention the name of the view -

```
return View("Register", model);
```

Your Unit Testing code should be something like this --

```
          public void DisplayStudent()
          {
             HomeController obj = new HomeController();
             ViewResult result = obj.Index() as ViewResult;
             Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.ViewName);

            Student stud = (Student)result.ViewData.Model;
            Assert.AreEqual("Sachin", stud.StudentName);
          }
```

Try to make changes accordingly.

If this is helpful then don't forget to mark it as answered. :)